# Обрезка анонса в wordpress до первого знака препинания?

Tags: wordpress

В сети нашел код обрезки анонса до первой точки.

```
add_filter(
  'the_excerpt',
  function ($excerpt) {
    return substr($excerpt,0,strpos($excerpt,'.')+1);
  }
);
```

Проблема в том, что этот код отлично обрезает content до первой точки. Но если стоит знак вопроса, то обрезка не срабатывает. Подскажите, как поправить этот код, чтобы он учитывал еще и знак вопроса? Спасибо.

Comment: Можете добавить еще один filter, но с '?' .

Answer (score 0):

Поискать регуляркой `"/[.?]/"` любой из двух символов как предлагают тут [Using regex in a string for strpos()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609915/3446071). И тогда в `$matches[0][1]` будет нужная позиция для обрезки.